# AdMob ban risk, anyone with specific info?

Tags: android, admob

One year ago my admob account had been banned for a month as I allowed beta testers to click on my banners, resulting in a lot of clicks and causing my 30 day ban from admob.

I'm working on a game and forgot to set my banner in test mode, so i started the game in my device, interstitial was loaded and generated money (0.19$) in my admob account, of course i fixed the problem immediately but I learnt that theres a risk of permanent ban for users who have already been warned.
I can't lose my admob account just because of one click.Any suggestions?Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's an option for you to request the admob team to not disable your account. Visit https://support.google.com/admob/faq/3364907#3365454 and go through "Can I appeal the disabling of my account?" and fill the [appeal form](https://support.google.com/adsense/troubleshooter/2707037)

Comment: hope this will be not necessary for just one click.. : (

Answer (score 0):

If you have list of all devices, please add them as TestDevices so that you will never recive real advertisments on those phone. Please refer admob sample code given to get device ID.

```
  // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
            .build();
```

Comment: already did that, just forgot one device one time and it show me one interstitial (paid in admob dashboard)